# Why isn't this Javascript function printing into my HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an HTML page that outputs random Mark Twain quotes. I have the function and quotes array set up in a separate (linked) Javascript file. For whatever reason, I can't get the output to show up on the HTML document.

*Edit to add: My apologies for not doing better research & finding that case sensitivity matters in cases like these. I'm a newbie :)

Here is my Javascript code.

```
// Quotes
var quotes = [
["The size of a misfortune is not determinable by an outsider's measurement of it but only by the measurements applied to it by the person specially affected by it. The king's lost crown is a vast matter to the king but of no consequence to the child. The lost toy is a great matter to the child but in the king's eyes it is not a thing to break the heart about."],
["Trivial Americans go to Paris when they die."],
["There isn't time -- so brief is life -- for bickerings, apologies, heartburnings, callings to account. There is only time for loving -- & but an instant, so to speak, for that."],
["Thunder is good, thunder is impressive; but it is lightning that does the work."],
["Everyone is a moon, and has a dark side which he never shows to anybody."]
];

// Generate a random number from the array
function random_item(quotes) {
  return quotes[math.floor(math.random()*quotes.length)];
}
```

Here is my HTML code with the output that isn't working. I'm not including the full thing because this is the only relevant part.

```
<div id="quotes">
   <script>
   document.write(random_item(quotes));
   </script>
   </div>
```

If it were working, each time the page is visited/refreshed, one of the quotes should display at random. They won't show up at all though.

Comment: `math.floor` Programming is often case-sensitive. Always check your browser console for errors before asking why things aren't working as expected

Comment: `Math` has a capital `M`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Wow, didn't realize it was that simple of a solution. Thank you

Comment: `F12` Console is a great way to spot errors before coming to S.O. to ask for help

Comment: @Taplar thank you, will definitely be using that from now on first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo with the `Math` object.

And consider avoiding putting script inside div

```js
// Quotes
var quotes = [
["The size of a misfortune is not determinable by an outsider's measurement of it but only by the measurements applied to it by the person specially affected by it. The king's lost crown is a vast matter to the king but of no consequence to the child. The lost toy is a great matter to the child but in the king's eyes it is not a thing to break the heart about."],
["Trivial Americans go to Paris when they die."],
["There isn't time -- so brief is life -- for bickerings, apologies, heartburnings, callings to account. There is only time for loving -- & but an instant, so to speak, for that."],
["Thunder is good, thunder is impressive; but it is lightning that does the work."],
["Everyone is a moon, and has a dark side which he never shows to anybody."]
];

// Generate a random number from the array
function random_item(quotes) {
  return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];
}

document.querySelector('#quotes').innerText = random_item(quotes);  // use instead of document.write
```

```html
<div id="quotes">
   </div>
```